# Add nested values to current dictionary composed of lists of values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have made a dictionary called ogseqs which contains orthogroup IDs (called og) which correspond to a list of genes.

```
ogseqs[og]=genelist 
{'OG0000000': ['Acrchr1_1567', 'Acrchr1_2725', 'Acrchr1_2932']}
```

I want to create a nested dictionary which will also contain the sequence for each gene in the genelist. I have made another dictionary called geneseqs with the genes corresponding to their sequences.

```
geneseqs[geneID]=sequence
geneseqs = {'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAFL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...', 'Annmae1_197712': 'MAF...', 'Annmor1_367154': 'MLF...', 'Annmae1_150166': 'MFL...'}
```

I'm having trouble merging/nesting these dictionaries. I've tried simply assigning the sequence like this:

```
genelist:['Acrchr1_1567', 'Acrchr1_2725', 'Acrchr1_2932']

ogseqs={'OG0000000': ['Acrchr1_1567', 'Acrchr1_2725', 'Acrchr1_2932']}
geneseqs={'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...'}

ogseqs[og][geneID]={}

for geneID in genelist:
    if geneID in geneseqs.keys():
        ogseqs[og][geneID]=sequence
```

but I get

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

So I think part of the problem is that the values in ogseqs are in a list instead of being individual values. I think this means I need to add a line that will divide this list before assigning nested values.

full input:

```
ogseqs = {'OG0000000': ['Acrchr1_1567', 'Acrchr1_2725', 'Acrchr1_2932'], 'OG0000001': ['Annmae1_197712', 'Annmor1_367154', 'Annmae1_150166']}
geneseqs = {'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAFL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...', 'Annmae1_197712': 'MAF...', 'Annmor1_367154': 'MLF...', 'Annmae1_150166': 'MFL...'}
```

expected output:

```
{'OG0000000': {'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...'}, 
'OG0000001': {'Annmae1_197712': 'MAF...', 'Annmor1_367154': 'MLF...', 'Annmae1_150166': 'MFL...'}}
```

Comment: What is the exact input you have right now?

Comment: I've added the exact input to help clarify

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. We don't have your file. For us to start working on, please give actual data. For ex: suppose you want to find max of a list, you should provide sthg like input: `[1,2,5,3,7,4]`, expected output: 7, current code: <code>, current output: 3. For that we don't need to know how this list is formed.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me here. The input is very long, so to simplify things can shorten them and say the input is the ogseqs dictionary {'OG0000000': ['Acrchr1_1567', 'Acrchr1_2725', 'Acrchr1_2932']} and the geneseqs dictionary {'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...'}

Comment: if that's the case, I would like the output to be {'OG0000000': {'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...'}} essentially if we can get that to work, the full lists from my files should also work

Comment: giving only this information (along with the genelist), it still kicks back the TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Thank you again for the update. I haven't downvoted, but you have my upvote now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current data looks like this:

```
ogseqs = {'OG0000000': ['Acrchr1_1567', 'Acrchr1_2725', 'Acrchr1_2932'],
          'OG0000001': ['Annmae1_197712', 'Annmor1_367154', 'Annmae1_150166']
}
geneseqs = {'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAFL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...',
            'Annmae1_197712': 'MAF...', 'Annmor1_367154': 'MLF...', 'Annmae1_150166': 'MFL...'
}
```

Doing `ogseqs[og][geneID]=sequence` in the for loop won't work because `ogseqs[og]` is a list and `geneID` is a string, so Python complains that you're trying to lookup a list index with strings, not an int. The way to do that (but *incorrect* in this case) would be to replace that line with `ogseqs[og] = geneseqs[geneID]`. However, it would overwrite your existing seq list for that `og`.

You could update ogseqs *in-place* but that gets unnecessarily complicated. Creating a new dict with the structure you want is easier but may use up a lot more memory depending on your starting data vs data per loop.

```
og = 'OG0000000'
genelist = ['Acrchr1_1567', 'Acrchr1_2725', 'Acrchr1_2932']
nested_ogseqs = {}  # new
nested_ogseqs[og] = {}  # create `og` in the new one

for geneID in genelist:
    if geneID in geneseqs:  # don't need `geneseqs.keys()` since iterates over keys anyway
        nested_ogseqs[og][geneID] = geneseqs[geneID]

>>> nested_ogseqs
{'OG0000000': {'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAFL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...'}}
```

But if your goal was to plainly convert/create an nested version of `ogseqs` without a preset `og` or `genelist`, you could just do this:

```
#`ogseqs` and `geneseqs` as above

nested_ogseqs = {}  # new
for og, genelist in ogseqs.items():
    nested_ogseqs[og] = {}  # create `og` in the new one
    for geneID in genelist:    
        nested_ogseqs[og][geneID] = geneseqs[geneID]  # create `og` in the new one

>>> nested_ogseqs
{'OG0000000': {'Acrchr1_1567': 'MAFL...', 'Acrchr1_2725': 'MFA...', 'Acrchr1_2932': 'MLA...'},
 'OG0000001': {'Annmae1_197712': 'MAF...', 'Annmor1_367154': 'MLF...', 'Annmae1_150166': 'MFL...'}}
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
nested_ogseqs = {}  # new
for og, genelist in ogseqs.items():
    nested_ogseqs[og] = {geneID: geneseqs[geneID] for geneID in genelist}
```

---

The downside of this is: If a geneID is not in `geneseqs`, such as for missing or as-yet-doesn't-exist data, then the original `ogseqs` needs to be saved, to re-create `nested_ogseqs` later or the genelist for that og gets lost.

Comment: This works for the simplified version! Thank you hopefully it'll do with my full lists

Comment: Also, is there a reason my post has been voted down? How can I improve it so this doesn't happen?

Comment: also I'm not worried about the geneIDs not in geneseqs, so I think I can skip that step.

Comment: Then my shortened solution works fine. (You were probably voted down because the code for how to create the original dicts is not relevant. Putting in a sample of `ogseqs` and `geneseqs`, as I did in my answer, is all that was needed. Also, you didn't clearly show what `genelist` and `sequence` are, I made an assumption based on the other info in your question. These 4 things in the question give the info needed to provide an answer. If such things are missing, ppl get tired of asking and eventually you'd get downvoted or the question would be closed.)

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for all the help. My posts in the future will be more concise